# Django form class for unknown number of fields and type

Tags: django, django-forms

I am very new to the django framework. I am trying to make a web application that helps students learn multiplication.
I have the following problem:
Lets take the multiplication of 2 numbers for exampele 532 x 42

I want to create a form class that generates only the needed input fields for all intermediate steps of the multiplication.

```
  5   3   2 x 4 2
     (1)
 [2][1][2][8]
    [1][0][6][4]
 ----------------
 [2][2][3][4][4]
```

In this example the brackets should represent input fields. The [] brackets are normal input fields and the () brackets are carry input fields.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
class AnswerForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, product, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fieldsets = {}

        for index, multiplier in enumerate(product.multiplier_list):
            rowLength = len(str(multiplier * product.multiplicand))
            fieldsetFields = []

            for i in range(5, 0, -1):
                field_name = f'field_{i}'
                self.fields[field_name] = forms.CharField(
                    label=f'Answer {i}',
                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'answer-cell', 'tabindex': i, 'maxlength': 1}),
                    required=i <= rowLength
                )
                fieldsetFields.append(self.fields[field_name])

            # Determine if row or result
            if index + 1 == len(product.multiplier_list):
                fieldsetId = f'fieldset-{product.type}result'
            else:
                fieldsetId = f'fieldset-{product.type}row'

            self.fieldsets[fieldsetId] = fieldsetFields
```

I used fieldsets to group the different types of input fields. In the template i check if the field is required. If so I print the field. Keep in mind the above code is without the carry fields.